# Detect errors in ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation()

Tags: ios, vcf-vcard, abrecord

### The problem

When I attempt to create an `ABPerson` with `ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation()` using corrupt vCard data my app crashes. This is the console output:

```
2012-07-14 20:20:37.530 vCardTest[4418:707] vCard Syntax Error, character: 7 : /
2012-07-14 20:20:37.531 vCardTest[4418:707] Malformed BEGIN
2012-07-14 20:20:37.534 vCardTest[4418:707] vCard Syntax Error, character: 14 : n
2012-07-14 20:20:37.536 vCardTest[4418:707] Malformed BEGIN
2012-07-14 20:20:37.539 vCardTest[4418:707] vCard Syntax Error, character: 21 : i
2012-07-14 20:20:37.543 vCardTest[4418:707] Malformed BEGIN
2012-07-14 20:20:37.546 vCardTest[4418:707] vCard Syntax Error, character: 28 : o
2012-07-14 20:20:37.548 vCardTest[4418:707] Malformed BEGIN
2012-07-14 20:20:37.550 vCardTest[4418:707] vCard Syntax Error, character: 35 : s
2012-07-14 20:20:37.553 vCardTest[4418:707] Malformed BEGIN
2012-07-14 20:20:37.555 vCardTest[4418:707] vCard Syntax Error, character: 42 : g
2012-07-14 20:20:37.556 vCardTest[4418:707] Malformed BEGIN
2012-07-14 20:20:37.559 vCardTest[4418:707] Malformed BEGIN
```

### What I tried to do to solve it

- [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) don't mention what happens when the data is corrupt.
- I tried `@try` and `@catch` but no exception is really thrown.
- Since the framework is logging all these syntax errors, I'm sure it knows that something is going on. I just don't know how to catch that.

### Why I care about corrupted data

The input string that generates the vCard comes from different sources which I do not control, so a lot of the times the input data won't even be a vCard at all. I'm only concerned about parsing valid vCards that's why it is important to be able to detect non-vCard data and discard it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced exactly the same problem, did a lot of research, but couldn't find any way to catch the exception either.

Since the errors don't seem to influence my app, I simply ignore them and check how many valid vCards were found in the scanned data - in my case the vCard comes from a QR code and I expect it to contain exactly one vCard.

```
CFArrayRef vCardPeople = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource, scannedVCard);

if(vCardPeople != NULL && CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople) == 1) {
    // Successfully read one vCard, save it to contacts
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(vCardPeople, 0);
    // ...
}
else {
    // Display an alert view to inform the user about malformed input data
}
```

You said your app crashes - I think this is only indirectly related to the malformed vCard. Maybe it doesn't crash until a few lines later when your code is not prepared to handle the empty array.

Comment: You are absolutely right. My code depended on the correct vCard and was crashing because of that. I've implemented your option and it works perfectly. I don't really care about what kind of error is thrown (or logged) so this solution is great for my case. Thanks!